# Should I wrap my class custom exceptions in my class?

Tags: c#, coding-style

If I have an Exception which is only related to one class, which style is the best?

When I wrap it in my class like this:

```
class Class {
  //some stuff
  throw MyException();

  class MyException : Exception
  {
    //some stuff
  }
}
```

Or leave it outside of the class

```
class Class {
  //some stuff
  throw MyException();
}
class MyException : Exception
  {
    //some stuff
  }
```

There is any advance using one or the other solutions? There is any coding standatrds for this?

Comment: The exception you throw should never be private. Does that even compile?

Comment: Yes it compile, and the throwed exception is visible in the same namespace.

Comment: Your second snippet is not valid (non nested members can't be private). And.. answer is it should be outside the class and `public`, Otherwise how client code will get a chance to catch it?

Comment: It is a personal preference. Unless you really know it is never being thrown anywhere else in the project, I would divide it into two files. I typically order my namespaces according to types and not context. So in my case I would put the exception in the exceptions namespace :)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Yes, thanks, I edited it. Could you tell me a reason why better is to put it outside of the main class? First example still work, threw exception could be catched in the same or any other namespace with the type of Exception, but I see your point, if it private, client code will not be able to catch it specifically.

Comment: @smerlung will this not mess up the project after a while? I mean that the parts of one logic unit is not in the same place.

Comment: In my experience no, it will actually increase order in the long run. That said I am using Visual Studio, so I use F12 alot. If you use a simple text editor then it would probably be easier to have some units in the same file. All said, I still would agree with MVCDS: why not use the exceptions already in .NET?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> which style is the best?

It's a matter of design (more further).

> There is any coding standatrds for this?

The book "Programming in C# - Exam ref 70-483" says that

> It's best to use the exceptions defined in .NET Framework [except if there are] developers working with your code [that] are aware of those exceptions and can handle them in a more specific way than framework exception

Ask yourself if there aren't any other exception that may represent the same you want to represent and what data is necessary to extract information about what happened with the exception.

> There is any advance using one or the other solutions?

The first design says the class will handle the exception as it was a proxy, external code won't know what has happened, but probably will only be aware of different outputs dependig wheter the exception were thrown or not. 
Only the class, its subclasses (protected) and its "simblings" (internal) may work with it.

The second says the world will be able to understand what went wrong and do something about it; other classes are going to change their own flow to handle the error.